# Which type to select for Smart Banner in Android when creating a new ad unit

Tags: android, admob, android-banner

I registered in AdMob and I tried to create a new ad unit. Only two choices were given to me: banner or interstitial ad. I was wondering how to create an ad unit for smart banners that suits landscape orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select banner when creating the ad unit. Use this for smart banners in your code:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
```

Change in orientation would automatically be handled by the AdView and the smart banner would readjust to fit the portrait screen. That is the whole purpose of smart banner.

> Smart Banners are new ad units (as of v6.0.0) that will render
>   screen-wide banner ads on any screen size across different devices in
>   either orientation. Smart Banners help deal with increasing screen
>   fragmentation across different devices by "smartly" detecting the
>   width of the phone in its current orientation, and making the ad view
>   that size.

Source: [Link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/android-legacy/docs/admob/smart-banners?hl=en)

Comment: Means I just have to chose banner in AdMob website ?

Comment: yes, and set the adsize to SMART_BANNER when you write the code

Comment: hope that answers your question